# SL4J wrong tag? Should be SLF4J?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

There is currently a tag mapped to [sl4j](/questions/tagged/sl4j). I believe the logging facade library is correctly referred to as SLF4J. There is currently also an [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) tag.

Should the [sl4j](/questions/tagged/sl4j) tag be merged into [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) or should they just be made synonyms?

Personally I think [sl4j](/questions/tagged/sl4j) should be merged in to [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) since that is the name of the library (which is already intialism for Simple Logging Facade for Java, the domain name, and part of the package name for the code).

Project homepage: http://www.slf4j.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes sense, I've merged and made `sl4j` a synonym of `slf4j`.